# When did Lord Vishnu perform Vaishnava Yajna?

Tags: mahabharata, vishnu, yajna, duryodhana

From Mahabharata's [Vana Prava](https://en.krishnakosh.org/krishna/Mahabharata_Vana_Parva_Chapter_253)

> The name of that sacrifice worthy of virtuous persons, is Vaishnava. No person save the ancient **Vishnu hath performed it before.** This mighty sacrifice vies with that best of sacrifices—the Rajasuya itself.

When Duryodhana wanted to perform Rajasuya Yajna, priest advised him to perform Vaishnava Yajna in place of Rajasuya. He also told him that no one hath performed Vaishnava Yajna beside Lord Vishnu. I want to know that when Lord Vishnu perform such Yajna? Is there any scriptural proof in it's support?